# Show more/less for elements inside ngFor depending on offset height

Tags: angular

Consider the code in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqzpfj?file=src%2Fmain.ts. I am trying to hide the block and show "More" link incase the blocks go beyond the first line and go to second line. I understand that the condition i applied in ngif gets applied to all of the blocks so when block goes to second line and height becomes more than specified, all of the block disappear. You can try adding more numbers to the array and find the same.
I don't know how to uniquely differentiate each div so only the blocks that fails the condition are alone hidden.

Comment: I update my answer to create a component to enclosed all the code. I hope you like it :)

Answer (score 1):

This snippet seems to work.

```
import 'zone.js';
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  HostListener,
  Renderer2,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div #something>
      <div *ngFor="let i of visibleItems" style="display:inline-flex">
        <div style="width:50px;height:50px;border:1px solid black;">
          {{ i }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="" *ngIf="visibleItems.length < totalItems">More</a>
  `,
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  totalItems = 20;
  visibleItems: number[] = [];

  @ViewChild('something')
  something!: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.calculateVisibleItems();
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize() {
    console.log('resize');
    this.calculateVisibleItems();
  }

  calculateVisibleItems() {
    const containerWidth = this.something.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    const itemWidth = 50+2; // Adjust based on your item width, don't forget the border

    const itemsPerLine = Math.floor(containerWidth / itemWidth);
    this.visibleItems = Array.from(
      { length: Math.min(itemsPerLine, this.totalItems) },
      (_, index) => index + 1
    );

    // Manually set display: none for items that are not visible
    for (let i = this.visibleItems.length; i < this.totalItems; i++) {
      const item = this.something.nativeElement.children[i];
      if (item) this.renderer.setStyle(item, 'display', 'none');
    }
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

The `calculateVisibleItems` method is responsible for determining how many items can fit in the first line based on the container's width. It then populates the `visibleItems` array with the indices of the items to be displayed. The `onResize` method is called whenever the window is resized to recalculate the visible items.

The `onResize` method is called whenever the window is resized.

Answer (score 1):

We get the "wrapper" div and the "items"

```
  @ViewChild('wrapper')  wrapper!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChildren('item') items!:QueryList<ElementRef>
```

And create an observable in ngAfterViewInit

```
  moreVisible$!:Observable<boolean>
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.moreVisible$ = fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(
      startWith(null),
      map(
        (_) =>
          this.wrapper?.nativeElement.scrollHeight >
          this.items.first.nativeElement.offsetHeight
      )
    );
  }
```

So, we can use some like

```
<div  #wrapper  
  style="overflow: hidden"
  [style.height.px]="more?items?items.first.nativeElement.offsetHeight:null:null"
>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5]">
    <div #item class="item" >
      {{i}}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
<button *ngIf="moreVisible$|async" (click)="more=!more">
  {{more?'more':'less'}}
</button>
```

Where we need use box-sizing: box-model (else we need take account the "border-width"). We can use to all the aplication:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,*::after,*::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

or simply in item class

```
   .item{
      width: 50px;
        height: 80px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: inline-flex;
        justify-content:center;
        box-sizing: border-box; //<--this

    }
```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ldfkvr?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css,src%2Findex.html)

**Update** creating a component and a directive

Well, this looks like very farragous, so we can create a directive and a component to wrap all. We want that the final .html of our component become like

```
<div wrapper-more-less [itemHeight]="80">
  <div *ngFor="let i of itemsList" class="item">{{i}}</div>
  <button more [button-more]="'more|less'">
  </button>
</div>
```

The first is create the component `wrapper-more-less`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'wrapper-more-less,[wrapper-more-less]',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
  <div #wrapper class="wrapper" 
       [style.height.px]="more?itemHeight?itemHeight:null:null">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
  <div *ngIf="moreVisible$|async">
  <ng-content select="[more]"></ng-content>
</div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
  .wrapper{
    overflow:hidden
  }
  `,
  ],
})
export class WrapperMoreLess {
  subject: Subject<null> = new Subject();
  @Input() itemHeight: number = 0;
  
  more: boolean = true;
  @ViewChild('wrapper', { static: true }) wrapper!: ElementRef;
  moreVisible$ = merge(
    this.subject.pipe(delay(0)),
    fromEvent(window, 'resize')
  ).pipe(
    startWith(null),
    map((_) => this.wrapper?.nativeElement.scrollHeight > this.itemHeight)
  );
  redraw() {
    this.subject.next(null);
  }
}
```

See that have a method "redraw" to "recalculate" in case we need change the number of elements.

And we create a directive to make functional the button

```
@Directive({
  selector:'[button-more]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class ButtonMoreDirective implements AfterViewInit
{
  caption:string[]=['more','less']
  @HostListener('click') _(){
    this.parent.more=!this.parent.more;
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML=this.parent.more?
                            this.caption[0]:
                            this.caption[1]
  }
  @Input('button-more') set _caption(value:string|undefined)
  { const caption=(value ||this.caption.join('|')).split('|')
    this.caption[0]=caption[0]
    if (caption.length>1)
       this.caption[1]=caption[1]

  }
  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef,
              @Host()private parent:WrapperMoreLess ){}
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML=this.caption[0]
  }
}
```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lz1bgd?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

See that we can use a button or a link or what-ever e.g.

```
<div wrapper-more-less  [itemHeight]="80">
  <div *ngFor="let i of itemsList" class="item">{{i}}</div>
  <div more style="text-align:right"">
     <a [button-more]></a>
  </div>
</div>
```